# How to solve the compile dependency in Android NDK using MakeFiles?

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries, android.mk

I want to compile two static libraries by android ndk: **static1.a** and **static2.a**

But static2.a will depend on static1.a, how to solve the compile dependency ?

In other words, 
static1.a has a method `func1()` and static2.a will invoke `func1()`

Comment: Have you tried adding `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := static1` when building `static2.a`?

Comment: @Michael `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` is only valid for `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`